# Remove the Open Perspective button from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I want to get rid of the Open Perspective button on the side toolbar of eclipse because I never use it, but I can't figure out how to do that.

[image: Screenshot]

How do I do it?

Comment: Can I ask why would you want to do that? You're hurting Eclipse feelings.

Comment: You mean the `Open Perspective`?

Comment: Yeah that's what it says when I hover over it. Just the button please.